# Split Million WordPress Post's Into Multiple Database Server

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

Say I have 50,000 posts in my current WordPress installation. May be it will grow more than 5,00,000 post's in the future. Now I wanna Scale the database.

I wanna put ,
1-50,000 posts > database server 1
50,001- 1,00,000posts > database server 2
1,00,001- 1,50,000 > database server 3
N posts - N posts > database server N
And, when I will go to WordPress dashboard, I can see the total post count .. combined 3 database post ... Say 1,50,000 post's... Also, when an user will browse my site.... Different posts will fetch from different database.... (Only Read)....

Now, (write query)-
When I will write post... From WordPress admin, the post will get stored in another database server. Now, If I see ... Write Database server reached 60,000 or 70,000 posts ... I Will simply put this server in 'read' database cluster....
I will get another server for "write" , again 60,000 or 70,000 posts ...simply put it 'read' database cluster....
Like this N....

Comment: I don't think this will give the improvement you think it might, and it will make certain queries much more difficult to run and require something like HyperDB. Instead would multiple copies of the same database not be better? Or optimising queries and data storage to avoid common mistakes such as `meta_query`/order by `rand`/ `__not_in` queries/etc?

Comment: A relational database will become useless if you split data that way. How will it be indexed or searched when a single database server doesn't have all the information? Instead of splitting data, what is usually done is replication & synchronization of the same data into multiple servers, implementing different search mechanism with advanced indexing etc. Then the load balancers are used to handle different user requests. Also, always remember this key point on optimization: **don't over optimize**. If you have a system for 50k posts, optimize it for 50k posts, not for 5M posts.